# Agenda calendar/roster view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I would like to display an agenda that shows who is available for roster for the next seven days, with the following logic:

Looping through each of the 7 days, for each day:

1. If the leave starts today, show `Starts %H:%M`
2. If the leave finishes today, show `Finishes %H:%M`
3. If the leave starts and finishes today, show `%H:%M - %H:%M`
4. If the leave doesn't start or finish today but spans over today, show `all day`
5. Should include leave that start or finish outside of the 7 days but span the 7 days being displayed.

I am hoping for someone to point me in the right direction preferably using Rails and Postgres. I am not against doing the queries for each day since at most there will only be 30 days displayed, but also looking for reasonably performant code since there could be 100+ leave records per day.

First example that does not fulfill the criteria outlined above.

```
<% @dates.each do |d| %>
  <h5><%= d.strftime("%A %d %b") %></h5>
  <% @leave = Leave.where('(start_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (end_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)', d.beginning_of_day, d.end_of_day, d.beginning_of_day, d.end_of_day) %>
  <% @leave = @leave.where.not('end_at < ?', Time.current) %>

  <% if @leave.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @leave.each do |leave| %>
        <% if leave.single_day? && leave.start_at.to_date == d %>
          <li>
            <label class="label label-danger"><%= leave.start_at.strftime('%H:%M') %> - <%= leave.end_at.strftime('%H:%M') %></label>
            <%= leave.user.name %>
          </li>
        <% elsif !leave.single_day? %>
          <% if leave.start_at.to_date == d %>
            <li>
              <label class="label label-danger">From <%= leave.start_at.strftime('%H:%M') %></label>
              <%= leave.user.name %>
            </li>
          <% elsif leave.end_at.to_date == d %>
            <li>
              <label class="label label-danger">Until <%= leave.end_at.strftime('%H:%M') %></label>
              <%= leave.user.name %>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li>
              <label class="label label-danger">All Day</label>
              <%= leave.user.name %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <span class="label label-success" style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </span>
    <%= current_account.users.active.where.not(id: @leave.map(&:user_id)).count %> Available
  <% else %>
    <span class="label label-success" style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </span>
    <%= current_account.users.active.count %> Available
  <% end %>

  <br />
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run this code or which part you are unable to implement?

Comment: I don't actually receive an error, however case 4 and 5 don't work. As mentioned above the code is also pretty hackish and lacking in maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

In the model:

```
def starts_on?(date)
  start_at.to_date == date
end

def ends_on?(date)
  end_at.to_date = date
end

def covers?(date)
  leave.start_at.to_date <= date && leave.end_at.to_date >= date
end

def starts_and_ends_on?(date)
  starts_on?(date) && ends_on?(date)
end
```

In the controller:

```
@dates = # define the date range like you already do, I assume it is an array
@leaves = Leave.includes(:user).
                where('start_at =< ? AND end_at >= ?', dates.max, dates.min)
```

In the helper:

```
def relevant_leaves_for_date(date, leaves)
  leaves.select { |leave| leave.covers?(date) }
end

def leave_description_for_date(leave, date)
  if leave.starts_and_ends_on?(date)
    "#{leave.start_at.strftime('%H:%M')} - #{leave.end_at.strftime('%H:%M')}"
  elsif leave.starts_on?(date)
    "From #{leave.start_at.strftime('%H:%M')}"
  elsif leave.ends_on?(date)
    "Until #{leave.end_at.strftime('%H:%M')}"
  else
    'All day'
  end
end

def available_users(leaves)
  current_account.users.active.count - leaves.size
end
```

In the view:

```
<% @dates.each do |date| %>
  <h5><%= date.strftime("%A %d %b") %></h5>

  <% leaves = relevant_leaves_for_date(date, @leaves) %>
  <% if leaves.any? %>
    <ul>

      <% leaves.each do |leave| %>
        <li>
          <label class="label label-danger">
            <%= leave_description_for_date(leave, date) %>
          </label>
          <%= leave.user.name %>
        </li>
      <% end %>

    </ul>
  <% end %>

  <span class="label label-success">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
  </span>
  <%= available_users(leaves) %> Available
<% end %>
```

You might notice that I remove the `<br>` and `style` tags from the html. Please do not use `<br>` for styling or `style` attributes in the html. Add class the the tags and style them in your css file.

Comment: I started writing an answer but realized that your examples where much better. Feel free to take the preface if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann very much appreciated this looks to be pretty close, will finish my test suite and fingers crossed. Yeah completely agree with your comment regarding style and br. I was basically prototyping out a solution because I didn't know where to start with this one. I was also very reluctant to include the code but also seen people get closed questions because they were missing :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why case 4 & 5 are not working is you are not fetching the leaves which started before the beginning of day or which are going to end after the end of day. So you can fetch all leaves which have not ended yet.

```
<% @leave = Leave.where('(end_at >= ?', d.beginning_of_day) %>
```

And then in **application_helper.rb**, you can have a function like this,

```
def check_for_leave(leave,d)
 msg = ""
 if leave.single_day? && leave.start_at.to_date == d 
  msg = "#{leave.start_at.strftime('%H:%M')}  - #{leave.end_at.strftime('%H:%M')}"
 elsif !leave.single_day? 
  if leave.start_at.to_date == d 
   msg = "From #{leave.start_at.strftime('%H:%M')}" 
  elsif leave.end_at.to_date == d
   msg = "Until #{leave.end_at.strftime('%H:%M')}" 
  else
   msg = "All Day"    
  end
 return msg
end
```

In **html.erb** file

```
<% @dates.each do |d| %>
  <h5><%= d.strftime("%A %d %b") %></h5>
  <% @leave = Leave.where('(end_at >= ?', d.beginning_of_day) %>
  <% if @leave.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @leave.each do |leave| %>
        <li>
            <label class="label label-danger">
                <%= check_for_leave(leave, d) %>
            </label>    
            <%= leave.user.name %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <span class="label label-success" style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </span>
    <%= current_account.users.active.where.not(id: @leave.map(&:user_id)).count %> Available
  <% else %>
    <span class="label label-success" style="margin-right: 10px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </span>
    <%= current_account.users.active.count %> Available
  <% end %>

  <br />
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: It fixes the immediate problem but jamming everything into ApplicationController is actually worse than the original. Slightly better would be to use a helper.

Comment: I have mentioned application helper only.